# macOS Monterey Pycharm test runner error: SystemError: ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data

Tags: python, pycharm, macos-monterey

Background Context:
After upgrading my macOS from `Big Sur` to `Monterey` when trying to run a unit test using PyCharm I am receiving this error

`SystemError: ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time)`

It used to work before the upgrade as expected, so seems the upgrade broke the configuration.

Putting this up here after trying quite a few things. Have tried

Updating `Xcode`

Reinstalling `OpenSSL` using HomeBrew.

Updating all Homebrew packages to Monterey.

Reinstalling all Python Dependencies

Reinstalling PyCharm

Current OpenSSL Version `OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021`

Been stuck on this error for a few days, and tried quite a few things mentioned in the existing forums.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but in a different context. I installed packages by means of requirements file and after the installation when i needed to install other packages, I got the same error. So, I fixed it uninstalling the cffi package and removing the cffi package on requirements.txt. I applied again the `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir` and the correct version of cffi was installed. The problem was the cffi version.
**Note** First off, you need to install some SO according to your SO. [Visit this page for more information](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)